# Store a variable online

Tags: javascript, html

I do know how to use localStoarge and sessionStorage, but is there anyway to store a variable online (github), (for example a button, and how many times it is pressed, but people can see how many times it is pressed from multiple locations), I am aware of databases, but I only really need to store one variable.

Comment: You could use a key value store service, something like Redis as a service or Firebase.

Comment: You may find it useful to store a file on GitHub, then use `PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path` to update the file contents. To read the file, simply use a `GET` (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7654872/brian) mentioned, you can use the GitHub API.

You can have a file to store your variable on GitHub then update it using:

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

[Here is a link to the section of the GitHub API.](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

In order to store something which allow users to see and update you need a server. So, if you find database extra, you may use a text document in your server and access it wherever you need to update the value or just read it.